# Get Vuex state data by passing a variable

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm new on working with Vue and Vuex, and currently I'm trying to bind props to my component like this:

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="vuemodal">
  <modal :active="get('active')" :login="get('login')" :register="get('register')">
  </modal>
</div>
```

My Vue instance looks like this:

```
var modal = new Vue({
  el: '#vuemodal',
  store,
  data: {
    active: '',
    login: false,
    register: false,
  },
  methods: {
    get: function(item){
      var state = this.$store.state;
      return state.item;
   }
 }
})
```

My Vuex store looks like this:

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    active: 'login',
    login: true,
    register: false
  }
})
```

In the "get" method, I would like to bind my "item" variable to my "state" variable. So the result will, for example, be this: this.$store.state.active (and it will return 'login').
When i console.log state.item, I get "undefined". What is the correct way to fix this, or should I try a complete different approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lcjvo1yt/1/) from your code, It is printing the store variables correctly. Make sure to use proper versions of Vue and Vuex.

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    active: 'login',
    login: true,
    register: false
  }
})

var modal = new Vue({
  el: '#vuemodal',
  store,
  data: {
    active: '',
    login: false,
    register: false,
  },
  methods: {
    get: function(item){
      var state = this.$store.state;
      console.log("state is ", state[item])
      return state.item;
   }
 }
})
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. This is indeed correct, but I want to to console log state.item (item is the passed variable).

Comment: @c.smits item is not a state variable, its a passed variable, which you can just do: `console.log("item is ", item)`. Right?

Comment: Correct. I know state.active will print 'login', state.login will print 'true' and state.register will print 'false'. But I don't want to call these three, I want to call state.item in which "item" represents active, login or register.

Comment: @c.smits so what you need is `state[item]`, I have updated the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lcjvo1yt/1/), Please check.

Comment: Yes! I'm sorry if my question was unclear but I'm glad you understood. Thank you!